# Forward a tap event from a UIView to an inner TextField

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I have a xib `UIView` that contains a `TextField`. I want my `TextField` to gain focus when the Parent UIView get touched. What's the updated proper way to do this using **Swift 3+**? And is it possible to do this entirely from the storyboard? *(I'm currently on Xcode 9 beta, but earlier solution are welcome)*

Here is my code:

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable
open class MinimalEditView: UIView, UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var textField: UITextField!

    @IBInspectable
    public var cornerRadius: CGFloat = 2.0 {
        didSet {
            self.layer.cornerRadius = self.cornerRadius
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable
    public var borderWidth: CGFloat = 2.0 {
        didSet {
            self.layer.borderWidth = self.borderWidth
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable
    public var borderColor: UIColor = UIColor.intactBeigeLight {
        didSet {
            self.layer.borderColor = self.borderColor.cgColor
        }
    }

    public func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        self.textField.becomeFirstResponder()
        return true
    }

    public override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

    }
    public required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

First, in your `viewDidLoad` add a gesture recognizer to detect a tap action on your view. The view should be placed on top of your text field

```
let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(viewTapped))
view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
view.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)
```

Then whenever your view is tapped, assign focus to the text field

```
func viewTapped()
{
    self.textField.becomeFirstResponder()
}
```

Comment: I cannot override viewDidLoad as it's not a ViewController, it's a xib

Comment: @Jaythaking Sure, then set it up in your `awakeFromXib`

Comment: textField come up as nil and it crashes... but it's well connected to the outlet :'( ... What am I doing wrong

Comment: @Jaythaking That should not happen. Can you try to remove the connection, and then connect again? Or try clean the project

Comment: My xib is basically just a MainView with a TextField inside... You suggest that I put another View on top of my textField? Why? and should I still let my TextFieldDelegate in my class as I put in my initial post?

Comment: @Jaythaking You can directly add the gesture on self.view. That's simpler

Comment: I wasn't able to get it working... Thanks anyways for trying

Answer (score 0):

You can add UITapGestureRecognizer on your parent view. Handle the tap gesture, as whenever your view is tapped ,assign focus to your textfield.

In your awakefromnib add UITapGestureRecognizer as

```
let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(viewTapped))
yourParentView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
yourParentView.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
```

Handle tap as

```
func handleTap(_ gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer){
{
    self.yourTextField.becomeFirstResponder()
}
```